# Unwanted MySQL table name character capitalization

Tags: mysql, insert, capitalization

I'm executing an insert query, and MySQL seems to be randomly capitalizing a J in the table name, which causes the query to fail based on a non-existent table.

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO `member_job_classes` (`job_class_id`, `pay_step_id`, `effective_date`, `member_id`) VALUES ('3', '2', '01/15/2020', '<the id value>')
```

And I get this error from phpMyAdmin (DB name removed)

```
#1146 - Table '<database>.member_Job_classes' doesn't exist
```

Notice that there's a capital J that doesn't belong there...and I gave it a lower case. There seems to be something about the _j sequence causing this. If I put another letter in front of the "j", there is no unwanted capitalization. Of course, the query still fails, but the capitalization doesn't happen. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like a web ui correction maybe. Also for effective date - use a date type with a mysql formatted date `YYYY-MM-DD`, it will make searches on the significantly easier.

Comment: Please add what mysql version you are using and operating system.

Comment: The date will be formatted as you suggested. That’s something data validation should have caught before pushing the value through.

Comment: @nbk it’s MySQL 5.6.41-84.1 on a Linux BlueHost shared server